# DocuSign envelope tab's background color

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign with the service we're working on for one of our customers.

We face trouble that happens during the envelope update.
When we update envelope tabs, their values are burned into the envelope documents and when the envelope is opened for additional editing or signing, the customers see unreadable text (document text is overlapped by tabs' values).

I must notice we're use pure functionality of DocuSign when we face this trouble (we are not using any 3rd-party services to update envelope tabs).

As a temporary workaround we refresh envelope documents in the following way: we replace content of envelope documents with a content of template documents via DocuSign Java SDK. But this workaround requires plenty of sequential REST API calls to DocuSign which is very unstable.

We also noticed that once on envelope's signing page we change tab's css (via Chrome developers tools) to have white background color then the issue disappears as tab's white background-color covers the text burned into the envelope's documents under the tab.

1) Could anyone please tell if there is a way to change tabs' background color? Either via DocuSign templates/envelopes editors or via DocuSign API/Java SDK?

2) Will appreciate any workaround suggestions.
We need to whether prevent writing tabs' values into a envelope's documents or make tabs' background not transparent. Any of these cases can help to get rid of "shadowed"/"overlapped" text (as shown on screenshots in my comment right under this my question)

Thanks!

### Updates

The main problem is that during the signing process the tabs don't have zero transparency, or don't have a background at all.

Please, take a look at the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quxjs.png This is the signing process page and here we see that text from the tabs are placed on the text from the document and it makes like shadow effect.

And we're looking a way to get rid of this effect and have a clear, readable text.

---

Re: can you please check Under Admin if Sending Settings "When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients" is checked in your DS Account? If yes, then try by unselecting it and testing it with a new envelope?

Thanks for your suggestion, but "When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients" checkbox was initially unselected.

**Updates 2**

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Firstly, user creates a template with text tabs on UI. Then creates envelope with templateId using EnvelopesApi#createEnvelope(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition) that calls "POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes", in request body we send text tabs with their values.
2. In the next step we get tabs ids and values to pass them into update request:

   2.1. Here we get envelope recipients using EnvelopesApi#listRecipients(String accountId, String envelopeId, EnvelopesApi.ListRecipientsOptions options) method that calls "GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients".

   2.2. Here we invoke EnvelopesApi#listTabs(String accountId, String envelopeId, String recipientId, EnvelopesApi.ListTabsOptions options) that calls "GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs".
3. Here we compose request body from the tabs we got in p.2 and put update some tabs' values.

   3.1. And perform the following method EnvelopesApi#updateTabs(String accountId, String envelopeId, String recipientId, Tabs tabs) that goes to "PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs".

   3.2. After that we update recipients invoking this method EnvelopesApi#updateRecipients(String accountId, String envelopeId, Recipients recipients, EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions options) that calls "PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients".
4. And finnaly we use EnvelopesApi#createRecipientView(String accountId, String envelopeId, RecipientViewRequest recipientViewRequest) method that calls "POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient" to create a signing page, where we have our issue.

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of the issue as well?

Comment: @Amit K Bist please see this links

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQzRL.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqSXe.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quxjs.png

Comment: can you please check Under Admin if Sending Settings `"When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients"` is checked in your DS Account? If yes, then try by unselecting it and testing it with a new envelope?

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add the EXACT API steps you used that resulted in the signing ceremony showing tabs that were transparent to the text underneath. (And I still don't understand *why* you are placing tabs over existing text on the document. An explanation of the use case which requires this would be helpful for solving your problem.)

Comment: Hi, ~Amit K Bist, @Inbar Gazit, ~Larry K!

Can anyone please tell me, how to report this bug to DocuSign support?
We have a paid account in DocuSign. We are very close to the release date, but we cannot do it without resolving the issue.

Comment: Hi @fastovezz did you try by altering the setting `"When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients"` which we suggested in previous comment. Also please share what are you updating in Pt 3.2 updateRecipients?

Comment: Hi @fastovezz I also ran all above steps (except 3.2) using Postman and could not see any overlapping issue. Can you please capture your API logs by following steps [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), and share it along with DS Template to docusign.sso@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

textTabs has a field called `concealValueOnDocument` which does exactly what you want. These values will only show on the final completed envelope, but would be invisible during the time the envelope is in route (while others are sigining it)
if you creating it via the API - add this value to the tab.
If you are not - you can update the tab using this method:

```
PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/tabs
```

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentTabs/update

which you can also make using the Java SDK

Comment: well, that's not what I want... maybe I put my issue's description wrong.

Documentation sais: "concealValueOnDocument
When set to true, the field appears normally while the recipient is adding or modifying the information in the field, but the data is not visible (the characters are hidden by asterisks) to any other signer or the sender."

I do not want to hide tab values by asterisks, I want to show them without underlying text of previously updated tab's values.

Comment: please see my comment with links to the screenshots under my question. thank you!

Comment: You cannot change the background color. I was trying to find other solutions for you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't understand your use case or what problem you're trying to solve.

In the `tagger` view, it is a feature that the tab is slightly translucent. It enables you to place the tab correctly on, for example, a line in the document.

During the signing process, the tab has zero transparency. Any text behind the tab is occluded.

Can you describe your overall use case? Update/edit your question to do so. Also, please describe exactly what you're doing that results in a signing experience where a tab is not occluding the background.